# Is it possible to bind a socket with NIC Queue?

Tags: linux, socket

when i open  a new socket linex system automatically bind it to a NIC queu. Currently i have two sockets
and i want to bind them to two different NIC queues. My question is

```
1)Is it possible to bind sockets to nic queue pragmatically  or using some linex command.
2)If so please guide me in the wright direction.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not guru, but in my opinion you can bind only nic queue to some physical  processor core and bind your app to same core (process affinity).

See the CPU/Cache affinity [part](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Performance_Tuning_Guide/index.html#main-network).